# what packages do I need to install on Ubuntu to get ruby-opengl to compile?

Tags: ruby, opengl, ubuntu-9.10

I am trying to use the ruby-opengl package, when I install it the compliler complains that it cannot find the correct header files.  What Ubuntu packages (9.10) do I need to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libopengl-ruby1.8` and `libopengl-ruby1.9` have both been in ubuntu's universe repository since Hardy (8.04). Is there a reason you absolutely must compile from source? If so, you could try running `sudo aptitude build-dep libopengl-ruby1.9` or `sudo aptitude build-dep libopengl-ruby1.8`. That ought to grab the packages you need.